# How to remove the table name from array keys in doctrine query for symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

How can I get rid of the table name from the keys in the results.

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Apps')
       ->createQuery('a')
       ->select("DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y/%m') as Month,count(*) as Applications")
       ->groupBy(" year(`created_at`) , month(`created_at`)");
       $query->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_NONE);
```

Gives me something like

```
    {
        "a_Month": "2012/09",
        "a_Applications": "3447"
    },
    {
        "a_Month": "2012/10",
        "a_Applications": "565"
    },
    {
        "a_Month": "2012/11",
        "a_Applications": "689"
    }...
```

I need to get something like

```
    {
        "Month": "2012/09",
        "Applications": "3447"
    },
    {
        "Month": "2012/10",
        "Applications": "565"
    },
    {
        "Month": "2012/11",
        "Applications": "689"
    }...
```

Without the table name prepended, is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally Doctrine uses its own column names to build queries. The column names assigned by you are applied to the results during hydration. Because you used `HYDRATE_NONE` you get the Doctrine's names as no hydration is being made on the result set.

Use the `HYDRATE_ARRAY` mode and you will get an array with keys you assigned yourself.

Comment: Excellent, I actually tried this, but I didn't realize that the hydration was also being set somewhere else in the code I was working with

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Doctrine very well so there might be something native but you could try this (`$arr` is your results array):

```
array_map(function ($k, $v) use (&$arr){

    $ke = str_replace("a_", "", $k);
    $arr[$ke] = $v;
    unset($arr[$k]);

}, array_keys($arr), $arr);
```